# is it possible to mute a call while recording the sound in android

Tags: java, android, audio, call, voice-recording

I want to build a app where I want to modulate the sound in a call.I have written a code that record the sound nd play it in different pitch.Now I want this feature while calling.I want to mute the call record the sound then play it with diff pitch.How to mute the call but still record the audio.

Comment: I would think it possible, but what you're asking is difficult. It's going to require personal experimentation on your part. I'd suggest you try it out for yourself. If it doesn't work, try using the speaker phone microphone. If that still doesn't work, try the same thing on a different Android phone. I found that functionality like that does vary between phones.

Comment: if you ever got this to work, can you share the answer?

Answer (score 5):

This answer works to mute your microphone during a call:

```
Boolean isMuted = false;
```

Then in your event, say an `onClick`

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(!isMuted){

   if((audioManager.getMode()== AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)||(audioManager.getMode()== AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)){
   audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
  }
  isMuted = true;

 }else{

  if((audioManager.getMode()== AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)||(audioManager.getMode()== AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)){
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
    }
  isMuted = false;
 }
```

Remember to enable permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.
set permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Step 2.
reverse microphone status

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
     (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (audioManager!=null) {
     audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(!audioManager.isMicrophoneMute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make `AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(boolean)` work on my Honor device, but I found another way to do this. I needed this funcionality in my custom dial app, so I already had custom InCallService, intercepting all calls. This class has method `setMuted(boolean state)` which works perfectly.